# Error in [MKStoreManager sharedManager] in IPhone?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have an application in which I am implementing **MKStorekit4** to have autorenewable purchases. I have successfully copied the code. When I am trying to call `[MKStoreManager sharedManager];` on my appdelegate it will throws an error `"cannot add nil observer"` then it crashes.

This is my code

```
+ (MKStoreManager*)sharedManager
{
    @synchronized(self) {

        if (_sharedStoreManager == nil) {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
            NSLog(@"You are running in Simulator MKStoreKit runs only on devices");

#else
            _sharedStoreManager = [[self alloc] init];                  
            _sharedStoreManager.purchasableObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [_sharedStoreManager requestProductData];                       
            _sharedStoreManager.storeObserver = [[MKStoreObserver alloc] init];

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] 
addTransactionObserver:_sharedStoreManager.storeObserver];            
            [_sharedStoreManager startVerifyingSubscriptionReceipts];

#endif

        }
    }
    return _sharedStoreManager;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that your `_sharedStoreManager.storeObserver` is nil.
But that's really strange.

Try to `NSLog("Observer %@",[_sharedStoreManager.storeObserver description])` after `_sharedStoreManager.storeObserver = [[MKStoreObserver alloc] init];` to see if it has really allocated.